# Issues with a jquery function on IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I want to show and hide an element with a click of a button but it doesnt' work, it works on chrome but not on IE8. At start of the page you need to see only the first div and all the other should be hidden (this works on ie8) but then when i click on next button it should hide the first one and show only the second div.
I am using `jQuery 1.7.1`.
please see the code below .

im so sorry this is all the page code

```
<html>

<HEAD>
<style type="text/css" >
form{
    background:#06F;

}
span{
    float:left;
}
#q1{
    display:block;  
}
#q2{
    display:none;
}
#q3{
    display:none;
}
#q4{
    display:none;
}
#q5{
    display:none;
}
input{
    float:left;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">


var ans = new Array;
var done = new Array;
var yourAns = new Array;
var explainAnswer = new Array;

var score = 0;
ans[1] = "b";
ans[2] = "b";
ans[3] = "a";
ans[4] = "c";
ans[5] = "b";

explainAnswer[1]="The reason why Answer 1 is Blah Blah Blah";
explainAnswer[2]="The reason why Answer 2 is Blah Blah Blah";
explainAnswer[3]="The reason why Answer 3 is Blah Blah Blah";
explainAnswer[4]="The reason why Answer 4 is Blah Blah Blah";
explainAnswer[5]="The reason why Answer 5 is Blah Blah Blah";

function Engine(question, answer) {
yourAns[question]=answer;
}

function Score(){
var answerText = "How did you do?\n------------------------------------\n";
for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
   answerText=answerText+"\nQuestion :"+i+"\n";
  if(ans[i]!=yourAns[i]){
    answerText=answerText+"\nThe correct answer was "+ans[i]+"\n"+explainAnswer[i]+"\n";
  }
  else{
    answerText=answerText+" \nCorrect! \n";
    score++;
  }
}

answerText=answerText+"\n\nYour total score is : "+score+"\n";

//now score the user
answerText=answerText+"\nComment : ";
if(score<=0){
answerText=answerText+"You need to learn some more";
}
if(score>=1 && score <=2){
answerText=answerText+"bit more practice";
}
if(score>=3 && score <=3){
answerText=answerText+"doing ok";
}
if(score>4){
answerText=answerText+"You are one hot java babe!";
}

alert(answerText);
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("\\omriljedocpd01\OMRILAPPS\OmrilDocs\Omrix Public\All Omrix Public\Training", true);
s.WriteLine(answerText);
s.Close();

}

function toggleDivStart(divId) {
   $("#q1").toggle();
   $("#q2").toggle();
   $("#q3").toggle();
   $("#q4").toggle();
   $("#q5").toggle();
}
function toggleDiv12(divId) {
   $("#q1").toggle();
   $("#q2").toggle();
}
function toggleDiv23(divId) {
   $("#q2").toggle();
   $("#q3").toggle();
}

function toggleDiv34(divId) {
   $("#q3").toggle();
   $("#q4").toggle();
}
function toggleDiv45(divId) {
   $("#q4").toggle();
   $("#q5").toggle();
}
$(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });

</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<DIV ALIGN="CENTER">
<h1>Java Quiz</h1>
<b>Test your knowledge of Java!</b>
<hr>
<FORM>

<div id="q1">
<b>1. What is the name of the Java mascot?</b><br>
<input type=radio name="q1" value="a" onClick="Engine(1, this.value)"><span>a) Luke</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q1" value="b" onClick="Engine(1, this.value)"><span>b) Duke</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q1" value="c" onClick="Engine(1, this.value)"><span>c) Nuke</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q1" value="d" onClick="Engine(1, this.value)"><span>d) Sunny</span><p>
  <button id="removeClass"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv12('q1');" >Next</a></button>

</div>
<div id="q2">
<b>2. Where is the best place to get Java software?</b><br>
<input type=radio name="q2" value="a" onClick="Engine(2, this.value)"><span>a) From a can</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q2" value="b" onClick="Engine(2, this.value)"><span>b) From java.sun.com</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q2" value="c" onClick="Engine(2, this.value)"><span>c) You have to buy it from Microsoft</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q2" value="d" onClick="Engine(2, this.value)"><span>d) From your local Star Bucks</span><p>
  <button id="addClass2"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv12('q1');" >Preview</a></button>
  <button id="removeClass2"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv23('q2');" >Next</a></button>
</div>
<div id="q3">
<b>3. A 'for' loop in Java looks like this....</b><br>
<input type=radio name="q3" value="a" onClick="Engine(3, this.value)"><span>a) for(int i=0;i<5;i++){}</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q3" value="b" onClick="Engine(3, this.value)"><span>b) for i=1 to 5 do</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q3" value="c" onClick="Engine(3, this.value)"><span>c) repeat...until(i=5)</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q3" value="d" onClick="Engine(3, this.value)"><span>d) FOR I:=5 DOWNTO 1 DO</span>  <p>
  <button id="addClass3"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv23('q2');" >Preview</a></button>
  <button id="removeClass3"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv34('q3');" >Next</a></button>
</div>
<div id="q4">
<b>4. Which platform can not run Java.</b><br>
<input type=radio name="q4" value="a" onClick="Engine(4, this.value)"><span>Linux</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q4" value="b" onClick="Engine(4, this.value)"><span>Windows NT</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q4" value="c" onClick="Engine(4, this.value)"><span>Commodore 64</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q4" value="d" onClick="Engine(4, this.value)"><span>Apple Mac</span>
<p>
  <button id="addClass4"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv34('q3');" >Preview</a></button>
  <button id="removeClass4"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv45('q4');" >Next</a></button>
</div>

<div id="q5">

<b>5. 'JMF' stands for: </b><br>
<input type=radio name="q5" value="a" onClick="Engine(5, this.value)"><span>A pop group of the 90's who had the hit "Unbelievable"</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q5" value="b" onClick="Engine(5, this.value)"><span>Java Media Framework</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q5" value="c" onClick="Engine(5, this.value)"><span>Java Messaging Framework</span><br>
<input type=radio name="q5" value="d" onClick="Engine(5, this.value)"><span>Java Meditation Forum</span><p>
  <button id="addClass5"><a href="javascript:toggleDiv45('q4');" >Preview</a></button>
    <input type=button onClick="Score()" value="Well... How did I do?">
</div>

</FORM>
</DIV>

<body>
<html>
<p>&nbsp;  </p>
 please help me
```

i have edit the code now this is the full page code that run on chrome safari

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code as well?

Comment: Please edit the title of this post. I assure you jQuery works in IE

Comment: This code isn't complete. Where is the HTML that it acts on? How and where is the event handler to change the displayed div attached to the 'next' button? You're missing a starting `<script>` tag, though that may be because you've selectively copy/pasted.

Comment: Some one please review the edits that I have done so that post becomes more readable, as do not have the necessary privileges to edit.

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing `<script>` tag in your example!?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual code you are using, then you're missing an opening `<script type="text/javascript">` tag. I see the closing `</script>` after your JS-code, but not an opening script-tag after your closing `</style>` prior to your JavaScript-code.

Answer (score 0):

you miss `<script>`

after the `</style>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function somewhere, No?

I see you declare them, what calls/invokes them?